# What should I put in google domain cname record for cloud front certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html

Here's info on the certificate I obtained from AWS

[image: AWS Certificate]

So the question is what do I put in the cname record at Google where my domain is registered?

I take it the name should be the certificate id followed by a dot and my domain name.  I.e.

a0580915-6797-450a-af71-32b2ffb27c30.friendsofbrooklyn.org

but it's not at all clear to me what I should use for the data.  I'd guess some part of the ARN but what part and do I need to add anything?

The referenced documents says for example

_98d2646601fa951d53639ac514e785e8.acm-validation.aws.

but my ARN is

arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:456405940529:certificate/a0580915-6797-450a-af71-32b2ffb27c30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new certificate and make sure you select 'DNS Validation' as the option:

[image: DNS Validation]

As soon as you press 'Request' button, the next page will show the CNAME name and value that you should enter on the Google side:

[image]

Comment: If those values were available at the time I applied for the certificate, they are long gone.  And the email I received during authentication contain no mention of them.  Isn't this information available later from AWS?

Comment: I asked for and obtained a new certificate and no where in the process was this infomation provided.

Comment: Ok, I see what's up. That info is only provided if one requests DNS validation.  But one needs that information for DNS validation to work.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually updating the answer, LOL!

Comment: I have sent you an e-mail.  Please check.  If you have got it, you can remove your e-mail address from here